# points $P,Q$ are on the sides $AB$ and $AC$ of triangle $ABC$ respectively such that the circumcircle of triangle APQ is tangent to $BC$ at point $D$

Tags: geometry

points $P,Q$ are on the sides $AB$ and $AC$ of triangle $ABC$ respectively such that the circumcircle of $\triangle APQ$ is tangent to $BC$ at point $D$. also $E$ is on the line $BC$ such that $BD = EC$. line $DP$ intersects (for the second time) with circumcircle of $\triangle CDQ$ at point $X$ and line $DQ$ intersects with circumcircle of $\triangle BDP$ at point $Y$. prove $D,E,X,Y$ are on the same circle.

i just proved circumcircle of $\triangle CDQ$ and $\triangle BDP$  are tangent and $PY||QX , PB||CX, BY||QC$.

but how should i use $BD = EC$
[image]

Comment: This is confusing, a diagram would help to show where all the points referred to lie.

Comment: A circumcircle of ABC goes through B and C so BC can not be tangent? make a sketch of your problem.

Comment: @trula sorry i just fixed it

Comment: In your picture $X$ and $Y$ are swapped.

Comment: Fix the title, it is still wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as i said $CX||BP$ and $BY||QC$ now we extend $CX$ and $BY$ so they meet at point $F$. $\triangle FEC = \triangle ABD$ so $\angle CFE = \angle BAD = \angle PDB = \angle CDX$ therefor $EXFD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and $YDXF$ is a cyclic quadrilateral too, therefor points $X,E,D,Y,F$ are all on the same circle